# How to set column name for DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I need to convert some data from a list of string and put it to datagrid, by using datatable.

I tried some code from [this website](http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-list-datatable):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Example list.
            List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
            list.Add(new string[] { "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3" });
            list.Add(new string[] { "Row 2", "Row 2" });
            list.Add(new string[] { "Row 3" });

            // Convert to DataTable.
            DataTable table = ConvertListToDataTable(list);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        }

        static DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(List<string[]> list)
        {
             // New table.
             DataTable table = new DataTable();

             // Get max columns.
             int columns = 0;
             foreach (var array in list)
             {
                 if (array.Length > columns)
                 {
                      columns = array.Length;
                 }
             }

             // Add columns.
             for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
             {
                 table.Columns.Add();
             }

             // Add rows.
             foreach (var array in list)
             {
                  table.Rows.Add(array);
             }

             return table;
         }
     }
 }
```

It was solved my problem but how can I modify or add custom header text the column title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do that after lines:

```
// Convert to DataTable.
DataTable table = ConvertListToDataTable(list);
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

set header

```
dataGridView1.Columns["ColumnName"].HeaderText = "Header";
```

Comment: I need to define my own ColumnName?

Comment: you have "Column 1","Column 2", etc. Put them instead of "ColumnName" and set appropriate header instead of "Header"

Answer (score 1):

```
dataGridView1.Columns["ColumnName"].Name = "Name";
```

**For example:**

```
dgvE.Columns[0].Name = "Dsomething";
dgvEditShift.Columns[1].Name = "Dsomething";
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding your columns, you can specify name and header this way :

```
table.Columns.Add("Name", "Header");
```